# How to query Active Directory for all groups and group members?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I'm looking at the [`DirectoryServices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx) namespace and I'm trying to get a list of all groups in the AD and load them into a listbox.

When I select a group, I want it to fill a text box with the manager's name as well another listbox with all users assigned to that group. I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around the process. Could someone help me out?

If I get a full example of this, I'm fairly sure that I'll understand the bigger picture a lot better. TIA

Comment: Have you viewed this reference?: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C#

Comment: yes, but I'm not exactly sure which ones apply to me or how to apply them to my goal

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find Active Directory groups where group name like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26984022/find-active-directory-groups-where-group-name-like)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're running on .NET 3.5 or newer, you can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a GroupPrincipal 
GroupPrincipal qbeGroup = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeGroup);

// find all matches
foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
{
     GroupPrincipal foundGroup = found as GroupPrincipal;

     if(foundGroup != null)
     {
        // do whatever you need to do, e.g. put name into a list of strings or something
     }
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`

When you have a given group, you can easily get all its group members by using:

```
// find the group in question (or load it from e.g. your list)
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "YourGroupNameHere");

// if found....
if (group != null)
{
   // iterate over members
   foreach (Principal p in group.GetMembers())
   {
      Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", p.StructuralObjectClass, p.DisplayName);
      // do whatever you need to do to those members
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I came up with something similar to marc_s using the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace:

```
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
GroupPrincipal queryPrincipal = new GroupPrincipal(context);

using (PrincipalSearcher searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(queryPrincipal))
using (PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> allPrincipals = searcher.FindAll())
    foreach (GroupPrincipal groupPrincipal in allPrincipals.OfType<GroupPrincipal>())
    {
        // Process group...

        foreach (UserPrincipal userPrincipal in groupPrincipal.Members.OfType<UserPrincipal>())
        {
            // Process group member...
        }
    }
```

The [`UserPrincipal` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.aspx) doesn't appear to expose any members that would allow you to determine if a user is and/or has a manager, but you can still do it by obtaining the [`DirectoryEntry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.directoryservices.directoryentry.aspx) for the user:

```
DirectoryEntry userEntry = userPrincipal.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

if (userEntry != null)
{
    bool isManager = userEntry.Properties["directReports"].Count > 0;
    bool isManaged = userEntry.Properties["manager"].Count > 0;

    // Perform further processing...
}
```

You'll need some additional logic, though, to determine if the user is a manager in the group you're currently looking at, rather than some other group.  Maybe check the `directReports` property to see if any of the users contained within are members of the current group.