# Find Active Directory groups where group name like

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

I need to write a C# script that returns all the Active Directory groups with group names that start with a certain name. I know can return one group using the following code.

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.Name, "Groupname");
```

However, I want all the groups where the Groupname starts with, say "GroupPrefix". I then want to traverse all these groups using the following code and store the "members" in an array/list that I can use later for searching.

```
foreach (UserPrincipal p in grp.GetMembers(true))
```

I would much appreciate any help that I can get with this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use a `PrincipalSearcher` and a "query-by-example" principal to do your searching:

```
// create your domain context
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
   // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a GroupPrincipal 
   // and with the name like some pattern
   GroupPrincipal qbeGroup = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);
   qbeGroup.Name = "GroupPrefix*";

   // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
   PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeGroup);

   // find all matches
   foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
   {
       // do whatever here - "found" is of type "Principal"
   }
}
```

If you haven't already - absolutely read the MSDN article [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/msdnmagazine/2008/01/16/managing-directory-security-principals-in-the-net-framework-3-5/) which shows nicely how to make the best use of the new features in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. Or see the [MSDN documentation on the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace.

Of course, depending on your need, you might want to specify other properties on that "query-by-example" group principal you create:

- `DisplayName` (typically: first name + space + last name)
- `SAM Account Name` - your Windows/AD account name

You can specify any of the properties on the `GroupPrincipal` and use those as "query-by-example" for your `PrincipalSearcher`.

Comment: Magazine link is dead.

Comment: Yes first link is dead

Comment: How to do this for a specific user?