# Using C# to get Active Directory users which have at least a group starting with a specified value

Tags: c#, pagination, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I have a `c#` application which uses `Active Directory`. I need to take all users which has at least a group starting with a specified value.

Here is my code:

```
using (PrincipalContext pcontext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "my-domain"))
{
    UserPrincipal uspPrincipal = new UserPrincipal(pcontext);

    // Here I think is the problem
    uspPrincipal.GetGroups().Any(x => x.Name.StartsWith("my value"));
    PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher(uspPrincipal);
    var results = ps.FindAll();
    var resMembers = results.Where(x => x is UserPrincipal)
            .Cast<UserPrincipal>()
            .Distinct()
            .Select(x => x.GivenName + ", " + x.Surname).ToList();
}
```

I receive a lot of users, but after I checked in `Active Directory` I found out that the number is bigger than expected result.

I know that I can bring firstly the groups that starts with seached value and then I can take for each group it's users but this means a lot of queries in `Active Directory` and I want to bring my users using just one interogation in `Active Directory`, so can I obtain neded users with a single search?

Answer (score 0):

`Any()` returns a `bool`, so that won't actually give you the list of groups that you want.

This question addresses searching for groups that start with a certain value. The answer should help: [Find Active Directory groups where group name like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26984022/find-active-directory-groups-where-group-name-like)

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "my-domain"))
{
    var users = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)).FindAll()
        .OfType<UserPrincipal>()
        .Where(u => u.GetGroups().Any(g => g.Name.StartsWith("my value")))
        .Distinct()
        .Select(u => $"({u.Name}) {u.GivenName ?? "No GivenName"}, {u.Surname ?? "No Surname"}")
        .ToList();

    foreach (var u in users)
        Console.WriteLine(u);
}
```

Comment: Thaks for your answer. I have a lot of users and groups in `Active Directory` and I want to ask you if this approach will bring all users from `Active Directory` and then it will filter them. If yes I will have a problem with execution time and I will need a more optimal solution