# Security group vs Distribution group

Tags: c#, asp.net

I found the following piece of code which lists all the AD groups from here 
[How to query Active Directory for all groups and group members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9487517/how-to-query-active-directory-for-all-groups-and-group-members)

```
 // create your domain context
 PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);

 // define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for a  GroupPrincipal 
 GroupPrincipal qbeGroup = new GroupPrincipal(ctx);

 // create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
 PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeGroup);

 // find all matches
 foreach(var found in srch.FindAll())
 {
     GroupPrincipal foundGroup = found as GroupPrincipal;

     if(foundGroup != null)
     {
        // do whatever you need to do, e.g. put name into a list of strings or something
     }
 }
```

I would like to know if there is anyway we can find if the groups listed are security or distribution groups?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There do exist the way to check out the type of group.

Please visit [Find out if a group in AD is in Distribution group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962483/find-out-if-a-group-in-ad-is-in-distribution-group)